# Nothing Happens after Clicking the Submit Button

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

With the generated code, one of my entities can not be saved. On the 8080 port, the form remains the same and nothing shows up on the console after I click the submit button. On the 9000 port, however, a log message shows fetching for related entities from the database after I click the button. There isn't an error message on any console, including the browser's console. In the dialog.html file, the first line is as follows:

```
    <form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()"
 show-validation>
```

so I insert the log in the first line of the Javascript function of the dialog.controller.js:

```
function save () {
    console.log("Saving ...");
...
```

How should I resolve it?

The structure of the controller is the followings:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyDialogController', MyDialogController);

SkuSDialogController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'DataUtils', 'entity', 'MyEntity', 'MyRelatedEntity'];

function SkuSDialogController ($timeout, $scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, DataUtils, entity, MyEntity, MyRelatedEntity) {
    var vm = this;

    ...
    vm.clear = clear;
    vm.datePickerOpenStatus = {};
    vm.openCalendar = openCalendar;
    vm.byteSize = DataUtils.byteSize;
    vm.openFile = DataUtils.openFile;
    vm.save = save;
    ...

    $timeout(function (){
        angular.element('.form-group:eq(1)>input').focus();
    });

    function clear () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    function save () {
    console.log("Saving ...");
        vm.isSaving = true;
        if (vm.myEntity.id !== null) {
            MyEntity.update(vm.myEntity, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        } else {
            MyEntity.save(vm.myEntity, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        }
    }

    function onSaveSuccess (result) {
        $scope.$emit('myApp:myEntityUpdate', result);
        $uibModalInstance.close(result);
        vm.isSaving = false;
    }

    function onSaveError () {
        vm.isSaving = false;
    }

    vm.datePickerOpenStatus.activeStartDate = false;
    vm.datePickerOpenStatus.activeEndDate = false;

    function openCalendar (date) {
        vm.datePickerOpenStatus[date] = true;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Is this mistagged? Thats Angular code not Vue.

Comment: You mean the "ng-". I check other part of code which is working and they have the same prefix ng-.

Comment: That and all the code you just added is Angular.

Comment: I am new to the front end code and Vue. That can be a mistake caused during a project creation. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: If this is Angular 1.x code, then in order to make your save function available in the template, you need to define it as $scope.save() {...), then you can reference it in the template the same way you do now (you don't use $scope.save... in the html).

Comment: It is the 1.x version. The code is generated, but not written by me. I have a look the save method and compare with a working code. I can't see a different in regarding of the method definition.

Comment: You have generated the app using JHipster, and the generated code seems correct. The save function is assigned to vm `vm.save = save;` so its already in scope. You have some other issue which is not apparent from the info you have provided.

Comment: @Deepu Please tell me what else I need to provide. I will be happy to provide any information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this in your html

```
<div ng-controller="(put here your controllerName) as vm">
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test it tomorrow. It is quite late in my time.

Comment: Please add explanation of the solution.

Comment: This is not required as the generated code already has scope in context via router assignment

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller,

```
 vm.save = function() {
console.log("Saving ...");
    vm.isSaving = true;
    if (vm.myEntity.id !== null) {
        MyEntity.update(vm.myEntity, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
    } else {
        MyEntity.save(vm.myEntity, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you trigger your vm.save() in button ng-click

Comment: Thanks. I will test it tomorrow. It is quite late in my time.

Comment: This is not required as the generated code already has scope in context via router assignment and the function is already assigned to the vm

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing submit button? `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` or `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a field name in the html file. The field name is "attributes". Once I replace the name, the problem is gone. JHipster AngularJS should have a better error message so that this type of problem can be pinned down quickly. There isn't any error message for this problem.